# Exploitability of AES in CBC Mode For Recovery of Plain Text

Tags: encryption, aes, cbc, pki

I'm aware of existing literature that shows in a comprehensive manner just how simple it is to tweak the ciphertext of AES-CBC such that the decrypted message ends up being entirely different than what it was originally (due to the lack of a MAC to provide AEAD).

**Can This Be Used to Compromise Encrypted Keys?**

Specifically, I came across documentation for a popular piece of software that countless individuals around the world use. This software package generates a private/public key pair for the end user (secp256k1) and encrypts the private key with AES-256-CBC.

**Wondering if CBC Mode Poses Any Issue Here**

To be clear, by 'issue', I'm referring to the outright recovery of the private key that was encrypted.

If the secret key is damaged / altered in this scenario, that's of no concern (for the question). Not sure if it makes a difference to add in that the key will be decrypted and re-encrypted as it is used (not sure if there is any leakage of the private key data that occurs during this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in this situation, CBC mode doesn't pose any security with a 256-bit uniform random AES key.

At data on rest, the AES-CBC has Ind-CPA security.

There is a padding oracle attack on the CBC mode due to PKCS#7 padding, however, that is not applying here since there is no server to query the padding.

There are multi-target attacks and quantum attacks on the AES, however, they are not possible on AES-256 which is the reason that it is the golden standard around.

The only problem that can occur on the user's side,

- User has a weak password that can be found, severe!
- User-machine has been hacked, severe!

Comment: Hey - thank you! This pretty succinctly answers my question. Sorry - I'm a bit new though, how can I get you the award for the question, or is it too late to do so?

Comment: Reward? Well, upvote an answer is helpful when you can. You need at least 15 points for this. Accept the answer if it satisfies you by pushing the check ✔️. Welcome and have fun. There is no late for upvote and accept. Only you cannot accept immediately.

Comment: Ah thanks for the quick response! Just confirmed with the check!